# Branches of implicitly defined cubic curves

Tags: cubics, implicit-function-theorem

Consider the following cubic curve defined by:

$$y^3 - 3y + x^3 = c$$

for $c$ a real parameter. The implicit function theorem guarantees three functions, $\phi_1$, $\phi_2$, and $\phi_3$ with domains $(- \infty, (c+2)^{1/3})$, $( (c - 2)^{1/3}, (c+2)^{1/3})$ and $((c-2)^{1/3}), \infty)$ that satisfy:

$$\phi_j(x)^3 - 3 \phi_j(x) + x^3 = c$$

[Cardano's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Cardano%27s_formula) to the cubic gives an explicit form for $\phi_1$ and $\phi_3$, but only outside the shared domain of $( (c - 2)^{1/3}, (c+2)^{1/3})$, as in this domain if we view the cubic as a function of $y$ we are in the [casus irreducibilis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis) with $3$ real roots. In this domain we can use the [trigonometric formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Trigonometric_solution_for_three_real_roots) for the case of 3 real roots to obtain explicit forms for $\phi_1$, $\phi_2$, and $\phi_3$ on the domain $( (c - 2)^{1/3}, (c+2)^{1/3})$.

I am wondering if there is a way to express these $\phi_j$ as a single formula of some well known functions. I am willing to accept the trigonometric solution for $\phi_2$, but am not satisfied by stitching the solution obtained by Cardano's formula to the solution from the trigonometric formula to obtain $\phi_1$ and $\phi_3$.

[image: Graph of cubic with c = 0]

Blue curve is the curve with $c = 0$. Purple line $x = (c - 2)^{1/3}$ and green line is $(c + 2)^{1/3}$. Cardano's formula gives an equation for $y$ as a function of $x$ outside of the lines, and the trignometric formula gives equations for the three branches of $y$ as a function of $x$ between the lines.

Comment: Should the upper limit of the first interval be $(c-2)^{1/3}$ rather than $(c+2)^{1/3}$ ?

Comment: I don't believe so, see the graph I added. Cardano's formula applies outside of the green and purple line, and the trigonometric line applies inside, but we should have functions constituting the top and bottom branches defined on $(-\infty, (c+2)^{1/3})$ and $((c-2)^{1/3}, \infty)$, respectively.

Comment: Thank you. The graph is helpful.

Comment: Elliptic curves may give rise to as many as seven $x\mapsto y$ functions, on seven corresponding overlapping intervals, for example $-5x^3+45x-4y^3+36y=0$. See https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/InfiniteMagicEllipticCurves/

Comment: I don't think I understand how what is going on in the link applies to this situation. Is the idea that the link is implicitly using a way of parameterizing points on these curves?

Comment: The link was cited as a source of various graphs; the collinear rational points aren't relevant. But the particular graph I cited shows that varying the coefficients can lead to more intervals and more (up to 7) $\phi_j$. That could be a pointer to some complexity in the more general problem. Even if your problem—to find real-radical formulae for the simpler case with three $\phi_j$—is solvable, I can't see it dropping out of a general theory without involving complex roots to generate the multiplicity of $\phi_j$ that can arise.

Comment: I experimented a bit with one of the cubics there that had 7 functions $y(x)$. There is a similar phenomenon of being able to write $y$ as a function of $x$ via Cardano's when there is a single value of $y$, and by the trignometric formulas when there are $3$ values of $y$. Desmos graph here: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fejqnkvd1u

Comment: Done in this trigonometric way, it seems that the multiplicity ($7\times$) arises from the ability to vary $k\in\{-1,0,1\}$ in formulae of the type $y=\cos(\frac13\arccos x+\frac23k\pi)$. Whether such a formula can be written algebraically in terms of radicals boils down to whether $\cos(\frac13\arccos x)$ can be so written. Thus the question amounts to whether there is formula, involving only radicals and rational functions, for any of the three real roots of $4x^3-3x=a$ in terms of $a$, where $-1<a<1$.

Comment: I'm not really following most of the question and the comments here, but one can get a "unified" expression for the roots of a general cubic equation using a hyperbolic cosine of a complex hyperbolic angle (of which the trigonometric solution is a special case of the complex hyperbolic angle being purely imaginary).  See my short write-up here: https://github.com/awalls-cx18/cubic/blob/master/doc/cubic_hyp.pdf

Comment: Here's a Geogebra visualization:  https://www.geogebra.org/m/a59xns3b  .  Move the $d$ slider manaully, or hit the play button to see how the value of the complex hyperbolic angle on the left plot affects the roots of the cubic in the right plot.  (Only the real part of the roots are plotted on the plot on the right.)